# Java Application Error while crypto control Code signing in firefox

Tags: javascript, cryptography, firefox-addon, code-signing, digital-signature

I have below error While code signing for `Firefox crypto control`.

Its a Java Script Application.

> psigntoolext_signArchiveFile(): xpsigntoolext_extractArchiveFile()
>   failed - ex : [Exception... "Component returned failure code:
>   0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [nsIZipReader.open]"  nsresult:
>   "0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   chrome://keymanager/content/tools/xpsigntoolext/XPSignToolFormSign.js
>   :: getZipReaderForFile :: line 537"  data: no